# Datatables async and Child rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Full name:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
        '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
} );
```

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Can i do child rows with datatables async or not? I tried add class 'details-control'  to head row but nothing happened.

I find this man https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html but 
it equal with no async.

How can i set details-control class to td?